# I am baffled why this javascript is not changing the color of my h2 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to color all strong and h2 tags based upon an earlier selection (male or female). I have done this to previous li and a tags, so I am confused as to why this isn't working. I must need to go buy a rubber ducky b/c I've been stuck for a while and this seems too easy.

CSS:

```
.colorPink {
    color: #a0426a!important;
}
.colorBlue {
    color: blue!important;
}
```

Javascript (passing in male/female string, this code does get hit b/c other stuff gets colored):

```
function SetGender(e)
{
    sessionStorage.gender = e;

    if (sessionStorage.gender == "male") {
        document.getElementById("category-list").className += " colorBlue";
        //..many other class/id color changes

        //Change H2/Strong tag color color
        $("#adviceBodyDisplay h2").addClass("colorBlue");
    }
    else if(sessionStorage.gender=="female") {
        document.getElementById("category-list").className += " colorPink";
        //..many other class/id color changes

        //Change H2/Strong tag color color
        $("#adviceBodyDisplay h2").addClass("colorPink");
    }
}
```

HTMLstuff:

```
<div id="adviceBodyDisplay">
  <h2>Real Life Example 1:</h2>
  <p>other text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why to mix `.className+=`(native) and `.addClass`(jQuery)? Why not chose one?

Comment: Side note, you should have a space before `!important`

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, complete and working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please?

Comment: Try "else" instead of "else if" to make sure if it's the js. It may be that gender is not initializing

Comment: BTW -- give your class names a good SEMANTIC meaning.. `colorPink` and `colorBlue` are horrible -- what if you have to change the CSS class for someone who is color blind?  Better to say `maleDecoration` and `femaleDecoration` or something else that is meaningful.

Comment: Is the colorPink/colorBlue class being added to the h2?

This is probably a css selector issue or a jquery selector issue, I would guess.

Comment: Check the inspector. Your class styles probably aren't overriding another style.

Comment: @Mr.Alien - I didn't say it was

Comment: If I remove references to elements that don't exist in your posted HTML, [it works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/hLLG9/1/). Any errors in your browser console?

Comment: I apologize for not giving the full example, I thought only putting in relevant code would lessen any convolution. @showdev, unfortunately, no console errors =/

Comment: @cephalopodMD unfortunatly I cannot do that, I have some gender neutral stuff that I do not want colored.

Comment: @j08691 It was implied (at least, it was inferred :-P). Always good to include a reason *why* to do things that aren't required, though.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Because I am very new to JS and JQuery, and was just going by examples from other people. During my recent pilgrimage into JavaScript and JQuery, I have found out that JS cannot handle tag selectors, so I switch to JQuery, and have been too lazy to switch everything over.

Comment: The issue isn't with styles over-riding, in the inspector the added class doesn't even show up.

Comment: @showdev Well, at the least I know that it should be working if it is working for you. Helps me narrow things down a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no element with the ID "category-list", so your Javascript is crashing before it gets to your color change